# File Permission of a User with No Additional Groups

Tags: permissions, group, useradd

Using a Rocky Linux server, I created a user using the following command,

```
sudo adduser foobar
```

and user `foobar` is now a member of group `foobar`. We can confirm with the following.

```
foobar$ id
uid=1111(foobar) gid=1111(foobar) groups=1111(foobar)
```

Notice that the `uid` and the `gid` are the same.

Now, for files and directories owned by `foobar`, are the owner permissions the same as group permissions?

**Example**

For the following directory,

```
drwxrwx---  1  foobar  foobar  my_dir
```

curiously, user `baz` who does NOT belong to group `foobar` has write access under `my_dir`.

```bash
baz$ id
uid=2222(baz) gid=10000(group1),10001(group2)
baz$ touch my_dir/test  # (?)
baz$ ls my_dir
test
```

The (?) line above: how is `baz` able to write into `my_dir` when the 'others' bits are turned off?

Comment: Can you try to `ls` my_dir/test from user `baz`? Can you try to write some content to the file as well? Also paste your `/etc/group` here eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux supports the basic file modes (rwxrwxrwx) but also supports ACL lists.
I *suspect* you have set some ACL list that permits baz to write.

```
getfacl my_dir
```

may show the situation.

Comment: This was indeed the case. The permission bits are actually `drwxrwx---+`. The plus sign indicates additional items in the access control list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User and group permissions in unix are separate, even if coincidentally named the same and/or having the same numeric ID.

The adduser command is not 100% standardized, and some versions create a group with the user and some don't and even the ones that do can be told not to, and ones that don't typically can be given a group name to create with the user.  Some versions of adduser if not given a group name, will assign the user to the 'users' group or some similar default group.

Also, the groupid and userid are only coincidentally the same (likely assigned to the next sequential one available), and these can easily become out of sync. (I find this annoying and sometimes bother to fix it afterwards.)

The other answer gives a plausible explanation why the touch worked.  Another possibility is that the 'test' file already existed before the touch and maybe baz has write access to the file but not the directory, or it didn't print an error in updating the time for some reason since the file already existed.